# How to install older version of php on mac

Tags: php

I am using MACOS High Sierra (version 10.13.3) and this one has PHP 7.1.7 installed. I need to downgrade to PHP 5.5.9. I have downloaded the tar.gz for that PHP version. Can someone guide me some guidance on how to install that?

**I tried** to install by following some info on web using **composer** as (Ref: https://getcomposer.org/download/ ):

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') ==='48e3236262b34d30969dca3c37281b3b4bbe3221bda826ac6a9a62d6444cdb0dcd0615698a5cbe587c3f0fe57a54d8f5') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

and the executed :  composer install from the directory where the composer.json exists. My composer.json looks like :

```
{
"require": {
    "rackspace/php-opencloud": "~1.13",
    "php-http/curl-client": "^1.7",
    "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.4",
    "php-http/message": "^1.6"
}
}
```

**However, the above attempt installed PHP 7.1.7**

**Another way , I tried** (Ref : https://tecadmin.net/install-php-macos/ )

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5.9
```

**However, with this attemp, ended up as :**

```
Did or could not download package: 5.5.9-frontenddev
Finished
```

I have now downloaded tar.gz for PHP 5.5.9 from https://www.php.net/releases/ .

Need some guidance on how to install that. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you need to downgrade?

Comment: do you have brew ? https://brew.sh/
you can install php old version 
https://blog.liquidbytes.net/2013/08/howto-install-php-5-5-and-phpunit-on-os-x-via-homebrew/

after that you can switch easily
https://github.com/philcook/brew-php-switcher

Comment: @SafakCiplak https://github.com/philcook/brew-php-switcher this is a life saver, thank you.